# URL UTF-8 Decoding Python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I am having some data in URL format and I want to decode it using Python. I tried the (accepted) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563126/url-encoding-decoding-with-python) but I am still not getting getting the correct decoding. My code is as follows:

```
import urllib2

name = '%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8'

print urllib2.unquote(urllib2.quote(name.encode("utf8"))).decode("utf8")
```

This should print `нотификатор-олимпийских-и` but it prints `%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8`

so I tried unquoting it again

print urllib2.unquote(urllib2.unquote(urllib2.quote(name.encode("utf8"))).decode("utf8"))

but it gives me `Ð½Ð¾ÑÐ¸ÑÐ¸ÐºÐ°ÑÐ¾Ñ-Ð¾Ð»Ð¸Ð¼Ð¿Ð¸Ð¹ÑÐºÐ¸Ñ-Ð¸`

I am not sure why this happens. Can anyone please explain where am I doing wrong and how do I correct my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many quote/unquote operations: you get a UTF-8 string that is *already* URL-encoded, why are you UTF-8 and URL encoding it again?

```
unquoted = urllib.unquote(name)
print unquoted.decode('utf-8')
# нотификатор-олимпийских-и
```