# Python 3.4.0 -- 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-15: ordinal not in range(128) -- Unix 14.04

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii, lxml

Trying to retrieve some data from the web using urlib and lxml, I've got an error and have no idea, how to fix it.

```
url='http://sum.in.ua/?swrd=автор'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

The error itself:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm using Ukrainian in API this time, but when I use API (without any Ukrainian letters in it) here:

```
url="http://www.toponymic-dictionary.in.ua/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=8&Itemid=9"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
pageWritten = page.read()
pageReady = pageWritten.decode('utf-8')
xmldata = lxml.html.document_fromstring(pageReady)
text1 = xmldata.xpath('//p[@class="MsoNormal"]//text()')
```

it gets me the data in Ukrainian and everything works just fine.

Comment: urls only accept ascii characters ... do a search and look in the search bar to see how thats encoded (something like `%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80` I assume)

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563126/url-encoding-decoding-with-python

Comment: Glad both Joran and I were of help! However, you can only mark **one** of the answers as accepted, not both. Pick the one you feel helped you most! (And yes, it is fine if that is Joran's :-))

Comment: Fine) The problem is solved and thank you for help!

Comment: Still it does not retrieve data for me - it gives me empty list. Although in here (www.toponymic-dictionary) it goes just good.

Comment: Maybe, the problem is with xpath, but I used Xpath helper in Chrome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLs can only use a subset of printable ASCII codepoints; everything else must be properly encoded using [URL percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

You can best achieve that by letting Python handle your parameters. The [`urllib.parse.urlencode()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) can convert a *dictionary* (or a sequence of key-value pairs) for use in URLs:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

url = 'http://sum.in.ua/'
parameters = {'swrd': 'автор'}
url = '{}?{}'.format(url, urlencode(parameters))

page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

This will first encode the parameters to UTF-8 bytes, then convert those bytes to percent-encoding sequences:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
>>> parameters = {'swrd': 'автор'}
>>> urlencode(parameters)
'swrd=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80'
```

If you did not construct this URL yourself, you'll need to 'repair' the encoding. You can split of the query string, parse it into a dictionary, then pass it to `urlencode` to put it back into the URL using [`urllib.parse.urlparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) and [`urllib.parse.parse_qs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlencode

url = 'http://sum.in.ua/?swrd=автор'
parsed_url = urlparse(url)
parameters = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
url = parsed_url._replace(query=urlencode(parameters, doseq=True)).geturl()
```

This splits the URL into its constituent parts, parses out the query string, re-encodes and re-builds the URL afterwards:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlencode
>>> url = 'http://sum.in.ua/?swrd=автор'
>>> parsed_url = urlparse(url)
>>> parameters = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
>>> parsed_url._replace(query=urlencode(parameters, doseq=True)).geturl()
'http://sum.in.ua/?swrd=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like below

```
 url = 'http://sum.in.ua/'
 q = 'swrd=автор'
 import urllib,requests
 requests.get(url+"?"+urllib.quote(q))
```

I think urllib.quote will transform `"swrd=автор"` into something like `"swrd=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80"`

which should be accepted just fine

Comment: You are encoding the `=` sign too.

Comment: bah ooops ... oh well +1 to your answer for actually being right:P

Comment: It can be done but you'd have to parse out the query string into parts first.

Comment: yeh your answer is actually what I was thinking of anyway ... I just dont do this url stuff very often so i forgot :P