# Encoding error when reading url with urllib

Tags: python, urllib

When I try to scrape a wikipedia site with a special character in its URL, using urllib.request and Python, I get the following error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf8' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)`

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request as ur

url = "https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonas_Gahr_Støre"
r = ur.urlopen(url).read()
```

How can I use urllib.request with utf-8 encoding?

Comment: tried writing this at the begging of the file? # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: Python version? Unicode handling changed drastically changed between 2.x and 3.x family.

Comment: can you try: .`r = ur.urlopen(url.decode('cp1252')).read()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL with Ukrainian characters giving UnicodeEncodeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260993/url-with-ukrainian-characters-giving-unicodeencodeerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, urllib can only handle ASCII requests, and converting your url to ascii gives a error on your special character.
Replacing ø with %C3%B8, the proper way to encode this special character in http, seems to do the trick. However, I can't find a method to do this automatically like your browser does.

example:

```
>>> f="https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonas_Gahr_St%C3%B8re"
>>> import urllib.request
>>> g=urllib.request.urlopen(f)
>>> text=g.read()
>>> text[:100]
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class="client-nojs" lang="nb" dir="ltr">\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8"/>\n<title'
```

The answer above doesn't work, because he is encoding after the request is processed, while you get an error during the request processing.

Comment: Thank you. I could write a manual converter for the characters I need.

Comment: There _is_ a function to quote a URL as the question this one .is a duplicate of shows.

Comment: yes, but urlquote will escape out the slashes in the url as well as the special characters

Comment: It won't escape slashes by default (but will escape the colon). There are [`urlparse.urlsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) and [`urlparse.urlunsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunsplit) to only process the specific part.

Answer (score 1):

If using a library is an option, I would suggest the awesome [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
r = requests.get('https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonas_Gahr_Støre')
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

New plan - Using requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def scrape():
    url = "http://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonas_Gahr_Støre"
    r = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r).encode('utf-8')

    print soup

    print r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - however, I sadly get the same error.

Answer (score -2):

Using the [answer from @mousetail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39229882/2169327) I wrote a custom encoder for the characters I needed:

```
def properEncode(url):
  url = url.replace("ø", "%C3%B8")
  url = url.replace("å", "%C3%A5")
  url = url.replace("æ", "%C3%A6")
  url = url.replace("Ø", "%C3%98")
  url = url.replace("Å", "%C3%A5")
  url = url.replace("Æ", "%C3%85")
  return url
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229439/encoding-error-when-reading-url-with-urllib#comment65800916_39229882